# Use only points within a polygon for heat map in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, heat-map, spatial-analysis

I'm trying to make a point density heat map where the calculation for each cell considers only points inside a containing polygon and ignores those falling outside it (mainly because the outside points are across a river or bay).

I figured out how to use Processing Extent and Raster Analysis to limit the heat map to the extent of the polygon in question, but it's still computing density for each cell based on outside points.

Is there a way to do this (ignore those points), short creating a new shapefile with points only within the polygon in question and then feeding that in as "Input point features" for the point density analysis?  I'm a novice user, so maybe missing something obvious...

(I need to use a radius size larger than the distance across the river, so decreasing that won't work.)

I am using ArcMap 10.3.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the select by location tool to collect the points inside the polygon of interest. Then run the heat map against only those points.